# Проблема: "WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip."

Tags: python, pip, python-3.8, warning

Пытался скачать библиотеку SpeechRecognition с помощью *pip install SpeechRecognition* вылезла данная ошибка "**WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.**" подумал что нужно обновить pip, написал *pip install --upgrade pip* и опять вылезла эта ошибка.

Версия Python 3.8

Comment: Warning - это не ошибка, а предупреждение. Наличие не самой последней версии pip само по себе не мешает установке пактов. Если у вас что-то не устанавливается, приведите полный текст ошибки установки.

Comment: Понял, видимо я не внимательно прочитал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

python -m pip install --upgrade pip Попробуй уменя сроботало

Answer (score 0):

Заходите в командную строку или терминал (НЕ IDLE), вводите:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

И жмете Enter.